# ¿Como buscar y filtrar en una relación adonis js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, adonisjs

¡Hola amigos! tenía algo de tiempo sin preguntar por aquí debido a que me ha sido facil encontrar solución a los baches que me he topado, no obstante justo ahora estoy frente a una muralla.

Tengo esta consulta :

```js
                const themes = await Theme.query()
                .with('users')
                .orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                .paginate(params.page, 3)
```

Lo que estoy intentando filtrar es encontrar el id del usuario en sesión buscando en la tabla de "users" para que no regrese el theme si el id de nuestro usuario existe, no obstante no encuentro forma de hacerlo... Intenté sustituir este metodo haciendo un Join en esta forma :

```js
const theme = await Theme.query()
        .select('users.id AS tenertema',
        'theme.id AS id', 
        'theme.nombretema AS nombretema',
        'theme.creador AS creador',
        'theme.estilonavbar AS navbar',
        'theme.estiloiconos AS iconos',
        'theme.estilopagina AS pagina',
        'theme.background AS Fondo',
        'theme.userbox AS ubox',
        'theme.postbox AS pbox',
        'theme.colortexto AS texto',
        'theme.moneda AS pay',
        'theme.precio AS price',
        'theme.created_at AS created'
        )
        .from('users')
        .leftJoin('interthemes as IT', 'IT.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        .leftJoin('themes as theme', 'IT.theme_id', '=', 'theme.id')
        .whereNot('theme_id', null)
        .whereNot('user_id', null)
        .where('user_id',user.id)
        .orderBy('created', 'DESC')
        .paginate(params.page, 3)
```

¿Cual es el principal problema de esto? es que al ser una relación muchos a muchos no me regresa el tema que pertenece a mi usuario pero sí me regresa el mismo tema en cuestión cuando pertenece a otros usuarios, es decir el objeto se multiplica con cada usuario a quien pertenece, ha sido un dolor de cabeza recientemente y pregunto tras dos o tres dias de buscar sin encontrar solución ¡Muchas gracias de ante mano!

Comment: No entiendo la duda, convendría para mejorar tu pregunta si puedes ser mas específico en lo que deseas obtener y tal vez un ejemplo de la data de salida que esperas obtener